# Powershell: Brute-forcing password-protected .zip file (speeding up the process)

Tags: powershell, zip, password-protection, 7zip, brute-force

First-time questioner, so here's hoping I'm doing it right. :)

A co-worker and I have been playing around with Powershell, getting the lay of the land and see what you can do with it. Using info we found online (mostly here), we've managed to whip together a script to brute-force a password-protected .zip file using a .txt containing a list of passwords:

```
# Stopwatch for measurement
$stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::startNew()

$7zipExec = """-7z.exe (7zip) location-"""
$input = """-.zip location-"""
$output = """-where to drop contents of .zip file-"""
$passwordfile = "-location of .txt file containing passwords-"
$windowStyle = "Hidden"
[long] $counter = 0

 # Correct password is 12341234

foreach ($password in (get-content $passwordfile)) {
$counter++
Write-Host -NoNewLine "Attempt #($counter): $password"
$arguments = "x -o$output -p$password -aoa $input"
$p = Start-Process $7zipExec -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru -WindowStyle $windowStyle

if ($p.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    # Password OK
    Write-Host " ...OK!"
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Password is $password, found it after $counter tries."
    break
}
elseif ($p.ExitCode -eq 2) {
    # Wrong password
    Write-Host " ...wrong"
}
else {
    # Unknown
    Write-Host " ...ERROR"
}
}

# Halt the stopwatch and display the time spent for this process
$stopWatch.Stop()
Write-Host
Write-Host "Done in $($stopWatch.Elapsed.Hours) hour(s), $($stopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes) minute(s) and $($stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds) seconds(s)" 
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

It actually works! Probably not as clean as it could be, but we've managed to reach our goal to make a functioning script.

However! It takes about 1 second for each password try, and if you have a file with, say, the 10,000 most common passwords...that could take a while.

So now we're trying to figure out how to speed up the process, but we've hit a wall and need help. I'm not asking for someone to get 'er done, but I would really appreciate some tips/tricks/hints for someone who has only recently started getting into Powershell (and loving it so far!).

Comment: 1. What is the size of .zip file? 2. Why aren't you using some dedicated utility that implements dozens of state-of-art speedup tricks? 3. I think there's no need for `start-process`, just execute it directly and use `$lastExitCode`

Comment: I doubt that PowerShell take more than 10% of execution time in your code. Most time taken by 7-Zip itself. Other than making your code parallel, to consume all of your cores, I do not see a way for substantial improvement.

Comment: You should check to see how much time it takes to run the start-process command.  That is most likely what takes the majority of the time, and if that is the case, then you probably need to multithread it.  However, that may get ugly if multiple 7zips are trying to access the same file at the same time...

Comment: @TonyHinkle You mean with Measure-Command? Multi threading was brought up by my colleague, but we'll need to do some testing for sure.

Comment: @PetSerAl Hmm, that's too bad... Still, a fun little thing to make!

Comment: @wOxxOm 1. 1KB in this case (just contains a .txt file with a sentence in it); 2. Cause we wanted to make something ourselves; 3. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: @Liam I've never used measure-command, but it looks like that would probably work.   You could just run `get-date -f FileDateTime` before and after that line and subtract.  You could also store the time before, then subtract it from the time after if you want code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to get back to this, real life and all that, but while I did not manage to speed up the script, I did manage to speed up the process.

What I do now is run 4 instances of the script simultaneously (using an extra PS script to start them, which itself can be started with a batch file).

All of them have their own lists of passwords, and their own output directory (I found that when they use the same location, the file extracted by the script that found the password becomes unusable).

This way, it takes about 7-8 hours to attempt 100,000 of the most commonly used passwords! While I'm sure there are quicker scripts/programs out there, I'm pretty happy with the result.

Thanks all for the input!